# Postgresql sql script execution

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to execute the following on a fresh Postgre started as a service on CentOS 7

`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -X -d postgres -f /home/user/Documents/test.sql`
however i get this error :

psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

my pg_hba.conf is defined as following:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

@remove-line-for-nolocal@# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
@remove-line-for-nolocal@local   all             all                                     @authmethodlocal@
# IPv4 local connections:
local all user peer
local  all             postgres  127.0.0.1/32     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
@remove-line-for-nolocal@local   replication     all                                     @authmethodlocal@
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            @authmethodhost@
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 @authmethodhost@
```

Why does the execution fail ?

Comment: This cannot be your `pg_hba.conf` file, because it is syntactically incorrect. It looks like a template.

Comment: I renamed the pg_hba.conf.sample into pg_hba.conf and restarted the service and this is the file currently with my modifications

Comment: No, there is a different `pg_hba.conf` file somewhere. Don't rename files that belong to the software, that file has to be called `pg_hba.conf.sample` and is needed for `initdb`.

Comment: the pg_hba.conf i renamed was located in /usr/pgsql-11/share , where should the original pg_hba.conf be then ?

Comment: Wherever you created the PostgreSQL cluster. Probably `/var/lib/pgsql/...`.

Comment: yeah true i was looking at the wrong location where the file it might be and i renamed file that does not need to be